# Точка отправления

Tags: c, библиотеки

В институте проходим си, а точнее синтаксис..и все это очень скучно.
Рекомендуемые учебники, как K&R освещают основы, где я могу найти api библиотек, сами библиотеки и их краткое описание? Ищу нечто подобное pypi питона.

Comment: STL в чистом C? o_O

Comment: ну простите, я дно - перепутал. Так или иначе стандартный набор библиотек, например math O_o

*оригинальный пост исправлен

Comment: в линукс `man 2 "имя функции"`

например

>[man 2 unlink](https://www.google.com/search?q=man+2+unlink)

Comment: @eicto ну для того, чтобы man что-то выдал, этот материал д.б. установлен. Те библиотеки, что включены в стандарт -- в стандарте. А остальные -- там, где есть. Много их...

Comment: @moron, можно начать с `ls /usr/include/\*.h` (как это ни странно).


А потом чтение, например, `man stdio.h` подскажет какие ман-ы почитать для освоения libio (скажем, `man fprintf`, ну это во всех книжках есть).

Правда, не для всех файлов в /usr/inclede есть ман-ы. Вот для zlib.h нет. Тогда читаем его `less /usr/inclede/zlib.h` и думаем. (Вообще, хотите освоить систему - читайте \*.h).

Некоторые файлы находятся в подкаталогах /usr/include (например, net/if.h), но все равно надо писать `man if.h`.

Для начала, основные - stdio.h stdlib.h math.h string.h limits.h time.h errno.h ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы пока еще не имели дела с линуксом и справочником man, то можно найти эту штуку и в нете, например вот [тут](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=printf&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD+9.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html). А вообще, функционал стандартной библиотеки очень хорошо описан в [справочнике по С Г. Шилдта в части 3](http://lord-n.narod.ru/download/books/walla/programming/Spr_po_C/main.htm#06)

Comment: Ай, только не Шилдт, пожалуйста. Он же ошибается и врёт на каждом шагу.

Comment: ссылки, на то, где он врет, в студию

Comment: Одна из первых в гугле: http://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn4e.html
Ну и вот ещё: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/schildt.html

Comment: @VlaD, спасибо, очень интересно :) Да есть такое - часть примеров написана безолаберно, не углубляясь в тонкости, просто чтобы показать функционал освещаемой темы(этим не один Шилдт страдает). Однако, просто обзор функциональных возможностей стандартной библиотеки на время первичного изучения в справочнике - удобный, а копнуть деталей можно уже в мане.

Answer (score 3):

интернет ими буквально кишит

[The C Library Reference Guide](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/index.html)

[Стандартная библиотека языка Си](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D0%B8)

http://www.codecogs.com/library/computing/c/index.php

Comment: 1997 год блин!(2ссылка) А где мне искать дополнительные библиотеки так и не сказали :(
закрою пожалуй вопрос, какой-то он идиотский..

Comment: @moron, я вот, например, так точно и не понял, чего именно Вы хотите?

Список всех библиотек?

Поищите, например, [здесь](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libdevel/) или поройтесь [тут](http://debian-counting.libresoft.es/lenny/index.php?menu=Packages&order=slocs).

Comment: @avp на такой вопрос есть и более простой ответ: на диске!

Comment: @moron, МТ была предложена в 1936-ом Тьюрингом, я в прошлом году учился по книгам 70-ых. Если ничего не изменилось с тех пор так какая разница?